# Python lazy attributes that don't eval on hasattr()

Tags: python, decorator, lazy-evaluation

Is it possible to make a decorator that makes attributes lazy that do not eval when you try to access it with `hasattr()`? I worked out how to make it lazy, but `hasattr()` makes it evaluate prematurely. E.g.,

```
class lazyattribute:
    # Magic.

class A:
    @lazyattribute
    def bar(self):
      print("Computing")
      return 5

>>> a = A()
>>> print(a.bar)
'Computing'
5
>>> print(a.bar)
5
>>> b = A()
>>> hasattr(b, 'bar') 
'Computing'
5
# Wanted output: 5
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be difficult to do. From the [hasattr documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr):

#### hasattr(object, name)

The arguments are an object and a string. The result is True if the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, False if not. (**This is implemented by calling getattr(object, name) and seeing whether it raises an exception or not.**)

Since attributes may be generated dynamically by a `__getattr__` method, there's no other way to reliably check for their presence. For your special situation, maybe testing the dictionaries explicitly would be enough:

```
any('bar' in d for d in (b.__dict__, b.__class__.__dict__))
```

Answer (score 3):

What nobody seems to have addressed so far is that perhaps the best thing to do is not to use `hasattr()`. Instead, go for EAFP (Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission).

```
try:
    x = foo.bar
except AttributeError:
    # what went in your else-block
    ...
else:
    # what went in your if hasattr(foo, "bar") block
    ...
```

This is obviously not a drop-in replacement, and you might have to move stuff around a bit, but it's possibly the "nicest" solution (subjectively, of course).

Comment: I agree that if I was refactoring I wouldn't rely on hasattr in a case like this, but I would probably prefer in any case to avoid attributes that don't necessarily exist. A dict-like object with `has_key` / `__contains__` would be nice and explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `hasattr` uses `getattr` so your attribute is always going to be evaluated when you use `hasattr`. If you post the code for your `lazyattribute` magic hopefully someone can suggest an alternative way of testing the presence of the attribute which doesn't require `hasattr` or `getattr`. See the help for `hasattr`:

```
>>> help(hasattr)
Help on built-in function hasattr in module __builtin__:

hasattr(...)
    hasattr(object, name) -> bool

    Return whether the object has an attribute with the given name.
    (This is done by calling getattr(object, name) and catching exceptions.)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you need something like this.  If `hasattr` ends up calling your "compute function", then so be it.  Just how lazy does your property need to be anyway?

Still, here's a rather inelegeant way of doing it by examining the calling function's name.  It could probably be coded a little better, but I don't think it should ever be used seriously.

```
import inspect

class lazyattribute(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, kls=None):
        if obj is None or inspect.stack()[1][4][0].startswith('hasattr'):
            return None
        value = self.func(obj)
        setattr(obj, self.func.__name__, value)
        return value

class Foo(object):
    @lazyattribute
    def bar(self):
        return 42
```

Comment: I did try that, but inspecting the stack doesn't help. The stack only has a __get__ call as it's first element, etc.

Comment: Tim, this works on my end.  Can you post your lazyattribute code, perhaps it's something else that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[orip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1286610/2754871) will be enough only if your object's inheritance has one level of depth.

You should iterate over the method resolution order of object's class to have a complete solution:

```
from itertools import chain

def lazy_hasattr(obj, name):
    # checks for the attribute without triggering __get__

    return any(name in d for d in chain((obj.__dict__,),
                                        (c.__dict__ for c in obj.__class__.mro())))

# Usage:
lazy_hasattr(b,'bar')
```

Answer (score -2):

well the fix is a little hackish but it consists of the following

1. rename hasattr (say as _hasattr)
2. rebind hasattr as the following:

```
   def hasattr(obj, name):
     try:
       return obj._hasattr(name) or _hasattr(obj, name)
     except:
       return _hasattr(obj, name)
```

3. implement class method _hasattr by checking some data structure (ie. array) which is populated with all the lazy attribute **names** (for an array you'd say: name **in** lazyAttrArray)
4. finally somehow have your @lazyattribute decorator add items into some sort of structure (like the array we mentioned above), and then when you call _hasattr then you look in that structure

   - *this is the step that I'm not quite sure how you'd implement 'cause I haven't worked with creating my own decorators*